# How to catch a mongodb error from mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

when there is a violation of the {unique: true} schema definition in mongoose- there is an E11000 error from MongoDB and not from mongoose.

when I use schema.save(err) - mongoose does not catch this error.

any ideas how to catch it from node.js?

here is a code excerpt:

```
var Plan = new Schema({
  slug: {type : String, default : '', trim : true, unique: true, required: true},
  title: {type : String, default : '', trim : true},
  body: {type : String, default : '', trim : true},
  createdAt  : {type : Date, default : Date.now}
})

.... 


// create new test records
   var planArray = [
      {slug: 'test', title: 'A', body: 'Lorem ipsum'},
      {slug: 'test', title: 'B', body: 'Lorem ipsum'},
      {slug: 'another_test', title: 'C', body: 'Lorem ipsum'}
    ]

   var arrayLength = planArray.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
      var p = new Plan(planArray[i])
      p.save(function(err, saved){
        if (err)
          {console.log("error creating fixture " + err)}
      })
    }
```

Comment: Any code would be useful...

Comment: see code excerpt now..

Comment: Code looks right.  Do the docs with the duplicate `slug` still get added to the collection?

Comment: yes they do, but on the mongod console I get the E11000 error but unable to catch it via mongoose..

Comment: Weird. Are you sure you're not targeting different databases or collections in Mongoose vs. the shell?

Comment: from the mongoose documentation: "NOTE: violating the constraint returns an E11000 error from MongoDB when saving, not a Mongoose validation error.". 
so not weird at all, but the question is - how to catch this non-mongoose error..?

Comment: Those errors are also passed to your `save` callback.

Comment: I checked the callback value and it only contains the doc, not the errors..